# Celery task fails midway while pulling data from a large database

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, celery

I'm running a periodic task using celery in a django-rest application that pulls data from a large Postgres database with multiple tables, the task starts well and pulls some data for about 50 mins and then fails with this error

```
client_idle_timeout
server closed the connection unexpectedly, This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.
```

What could be the issue causing this and how can I go about to fix it?

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: Its a 50 minute task and pulling data... out of memory? postgres timing out your connection because you kept it open for too long while processing?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, by querying small amounts of data incrementally hence preventing timeout. Thanks @paraschauhan and Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It most likely means that your PostgreSQL has limit on how long transaction can take (idle in transaction), or how long session can be (session timeout).

This is probably happening because of a typical, incorrect way of dealing with databases (I've seen this done even by senior developers) - process creates a database session, and then starts doing some business logic that may take long time to finish, while DB data has been either partially updated or inserted. Code written in such way is doomed to fail because of timeouts enforced by PostgreSQL.